# How to get Asynchronous tests working with Jasmine 1.3.1 and Atom

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, atom-editor

I'm following the Jasmine 1.3 docs on [Asynchronous Support](https://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction#section-Asynchronous_Support) and am having trouble getting the example working.

The (slightly modified) source code I'm using as `spec/async-spec.js` is below:

```
describe("Asynchronous specs", function() {
  var value, flag;

  it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function() {

  runs(function() {
    flag = false;
    value = 0;

    console.log("HERE"); 

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("HERE2"); 
      flag = true;
    }, 750);
  });

  waitsFor(function() {
      value++;
      return flag;
  }, "The Value should be incremented", 5000);


  runs(function() {
      expect(value).toBeGreaterThan(0);
    });
  });
});
```

I'm running it with the following command:

```
atom --test --timeout 60 spec/async-spec.js
```

and it is giving the following result:

```
HERE
F

Asynchronous specs
  it should support async execution of test preparation and expectations
    timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for The Value should be incremented


Finished in 5.746 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure, 0 skipped
```

I would expect the test to return both `HERE` and `HERE2` and for the assert to pass, alas this is not the case.

The `atom --version` details are:

```
Atom    : 1.38.2
Electron: 2.0.18
Chrome  : 61.0.3163.100
Node    : 8.9.3
```

And the exact Jasmine version is: `1.3.1 revision 1354556913`

I'm rather new to Atom/Jasmine testing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't an ideal solution as I would like to have stayed with the default Jasmine version for a few reasons, but I found installing the following package enabled me to get better Asynchronous support:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/atom-jasmine2-test-runner

I could then reference the Jasmine 2.9 docs and implement them correctly:

https://jasmine.github.io/2.9/introduction